# Input range returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

**Problem**

So, my problem is that my `<input type="range">` returns `undefined` on change. In the `changeCheck()`, I am checking which `<input type="range">` was changed.In my `addBrightness()`, I am outputting the value of the `<input type="range">`, when ever it is changed.

**JavaScript**

```
// VARIABLES
var canvas = $('#editor')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = '';
img.src = '';

var file = $('.file');
var open = $('.open');
var fileOpen = $('.file-open');

var control = $("input[type=range]");
var brightness = $('.brightness');

// MAIN
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(img).on('load', imgLoad);
    $(file).on('click', dropdown);
    $(open).on('click', openFile);
    $(fileOpen).on('change', getPath);

    $(control).on('change', checkChange);
})

// CHECK CHANGE
function checkChange() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('brightness')) {
        addBrightness();
    }
}

// ADD BRIGHTNESS
function addBrightness(val) {
    var value = $('brightness').val();

    console.log(value);

    /*Caman('#editor', function () {
        this.brightness(value);
        this.render();
    });*/
}

// DROPDOWN
function dropdown() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
}

// OPEN FILE
function openFile() {
    $(fileOpen).click();
}

// GET FILE PATH
function getPath(e) {
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    imgLoad();
}

// LOAD IMG
function imgLoad() {
    if(img.width > 800) {
        img.width = 800;

        if(img.height > 800) {
            img.height = 800;

            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/large.css" media="(min-width:800px)">

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FAVICON -->
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> File
                <ul>
                    <li class="open"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Open</li>
                    <li class="save"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</li>
                    <li class="exit"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Exit</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <center>
            <canvas id="editor"></canvas>
        </center>

        <div class="controls-container">

            <!-- brightness -->
            <div class="brightness control">
                <h3>Brightness</h3>
                <input type="range"  value="50" min="0" max="100">
            </div>

            <!-- contrest -->
            <div class="contrast control">
                <h3>Contrast</h3>
                <input type="range"  value="50" min="0" max="100">
            </div>

            <!-- exposure -->
            <div class="exposure control">
                <h3>Exposure</h3>
                <input type="range"  value="50" min="0" max="100">
            </div>

            <!-- sharpen -->
            <div class="sharpen control">
                <h3>Sharpen</h3>
                <input type="range"  value="0" min="0" max="100">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <input type="file" class="file-open">

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.0.0/caman.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e99695fe86.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not selecting the `input` for brightness correctly.

```
var value = $('.brightness>input[type="range"]:first').val();
```

will work.

Comment: Note that this may return an array since you will be selecting all inputs with  a parent that has the brightness class. Not necessarily a problem but could throw you off if you add another brightness range selector for something else on the page.

Comment: Cool. :) I believe ":first-child" is what you want.

Comment: yes. i've used `:first` to select only the first occurence. `:first-child` may select all first child occurences of each parents

Comment: Are you sure that's what ':first' is for? I can't seem to find it on W3 schools, but found this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first

It's true though that ':first-child' may select more than one, so it's also problematic.

Comment: yes. `:first` selector will only select one single element.

Comment: Oh I see now. ':first' is actually a jQuery extension and can only be used with jQuery, which is what he's using. That's why it was difficult to find. Here's the docs for that: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/ Make sure you don't use it in CSS!

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
var value = $('brightness').val();
```

...you are not selecting anything on the page. This will select the class:

```
var value = $('.brightness').val();
```

...but even that will fail, because it's the input inside the class that you want:

```
var value = $('.brightness input').val();
```

Also, generally I believe jQuery will return an array since you are not selecting by id, so you probably want to do something like this (not tested):

```
var value = $('.brightness input')[0].val();
```

If that's not your preferred way, add an id to the input, then you can use that:

```
var value = $('#brightness-input').val();
```